# Recursively create full binary tree of given depth

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

Given the tree depth **depth**, returns a full binary tree of that **depth**.
The tree structure is defined blow:

```
typedef int Item;
// Define binary tree node
typedef struct node {
    struct node *lchild;
    Item item;
    struct node *rchild;
} BTNode, *BTree;
```

I use a function named **CreateFullBTree** to create binary tree recursively. here's the function:

```
BTree CreateFullBTree(int depth)
{
    static int tag = 1;
    BTNode *node = CreateNode();
    node -> item = tag;
    tag++;

    printf("%d, %p\n",node->item, node);
    if (depth == 1) return node;
    node -> lchild = CreateFullBTree(depth-1);
    node -> rchild = CreateFullBTree(depth-1);
    return node; 
}
```

The **CreateNode** function is:

```
BTNode* CreateNode()
{
    BTNode *node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node -> lchild = NULL;
    node -> rchild = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

And main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int depth;
    scanf("%d", &depth);
    BTree pTree = CreateFullBTree(depth);
    preOrder(pTree); 
    return 0;
}
```

In main function, I call the CreateFullBTree to get a full binary tree, and then call the preOrder function to output each node's **tag** field to check if the tree is properly created. The preOrder function is:

```
void preOrder(BTree tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        printf("%d\n", tree->item);
        preOrder(tree->lchild);
        preOrder(tree->rchild);
    }
    return;
}
```

Each time CreateFullBTree is called, a new node is created and tagged. Then we check if current depth reaches 1 which means we hit the bottom of the binary tree. If so, we just return that newly created node and do nothing. If not, the node can have left and right children and then we let the `node->lchild = CreateFullBTree(depth-1)` and `node->rchild = CreateFullBTree(depth-1)`.

But the algorithm doesn't work as expected, when we take 3 as the tree's depth, the output of `preOrder`function is weird: 1 2 5 6 7 7 4 6 7 5 6 7 7, it seems some node's lchild and rchild pointers are pointed to the wrong node. But I can't find the reason why they are in disorder.

Can anyone help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate enough space for you nodes: `sizeof(BTNode)`, not `sizeof(node)`.

Comment: Awesome, it works! sizeof(node) turns out to be sizeof(BTNode *), and I find that sizeof(BTNode *) is 81 and sizeof(BTNode) is 24, it seems sizeof(node) is bigger than sizeof(BTNode) and why are they different?

Comment: On a 64 bits system, the variable node is an 8 bytes pointer while the type BTNode is a 24 bytes struct. Nothing is 81 bytes.

Comment: It seems that the confusion occurred because the word `node` is used both as a name of the struct and name of the variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, sizeof(BTNode *) is 8, not 81. Thanks very much.